# Odd degree polynomials at least one root

Tags: polynomials

Show that any polynomial

$$p(x) = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i\times x^{i}$$

with odd degree *n* has at least one **real** root (i.e., there is some $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$
with $p(c) = 0$). Why is the same not true for polynomials with even degree n?

I understand that every odd polynomial has to go through $0$ because of the higher power because as we move to $-\infty$, it will become negative. But I have no idea how to formalize it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Intermediate Value Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Intermediate_value_theorem) from calculus?

Comment: Sharing the source of this exercise would help your Readers better understand what tools you are expected to have to prove this result.  It would also encourage Readers to devote time to helping you if you explained your own research efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For nonconstant polynomials of odd degree, their end behavior is approaching $+\infty$ in one direction and approaching $-\infty$ in the other direction. Therefore, there exist $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $p(a) < 0$ and $p(b) > 0$ (this is a direct consequence of the definition of a limit going to $\pm\infty$). Since all polynomial functions are continuous, we can apply the intermediate value theorem to conclude that there exists some $c \in \mathbb{R}$ (between $a$ and $b$) with $p(c) = 0$.

For nonconstant polynomials of even degree, their end behavior is approaching $+\infty$ in both directions or $-\infty$ in both directions. Therefore, we can't say $a$ and $b$ both exists like we did in the odd degree case.

Answer (score 1):

A proof using **Complex conjugate root theorem** is in Wikipedia [Corollary on odd-degree polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_conjugate_root_theorem#Corollary_on_odd-degree_polynomials)

> Since non-real complex roots come in conjugate pairs, there are an even number of them;
> But a polynomial of odd degree has an odd number of roots;
> Therefore some of them must be real.